# I have a model in which i am getting one key value nil but data comes in json response is perfect

Tags: ios, swift, struct, model

i am getting clinic nil and i have mentioned my model and error message.

i have check and compare all key with json response key .

and my json reponse of clinic is in which i am getting error

```
"clinic": [
    {
        "id": 45,
        "user_id": "75",
        "clinic_id": "2",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "clinic": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Al Azhar Hospital",
            "status": "1",
            "created_at": "2019-04-18 07:01:07",
            "updated_at": null
        }
    }
]
```

---

```
typealias SpecialityDoctor = [SpecialityWiseDoctorResponse]


struct SpecialityWiseDoctorResponse: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String?
    let email: String
    let postMail: String?
    let mobile, age, password, gender: String
    let dateOfBirth: String?
    let profilePic, deviceID: String
    let language, insuranceCompanyName, insurancePolicyNo: String?
    let welcomeDescription: String
    let emrNumber: String?
    let startTime, endTime: String
    let status: Int
    let totalSubscriptionMonth, planStartDate, planEndDate, createdAt: String?
    let updatedAt: String?
    let speciality: [SpecialityElement]
    let clinic: [ClinicElementOfDoctor]
    let education: [EducationOfDoctor]
    let experience: [ExperienceOfDoctor]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case email
        case postMail = "post_mail"
        case mobile, age, password, gender
        case dateOfBirth = "date_of_birth"
        case profilePic = "profile_pic"
        case deviceID = "device_id"
        case language
        case insuranceCompanyName = "insurance_company_name"
        case insurancePolicyNo = "insurance_policy_no"
        case welcomeDescription = "description"
        case emrNumber = "emr_number"
        case startTime = "start_time"
        case endTime = "end_time"
        case status
        case totalSubscriptionMonth = "total_subscription_month"
        case planStartDate = "plan_start_date"
        case planEndDate = "plan_end_date"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
        case speciality, clinic, education, experience
    }
}


struct ClinicElementOfDoctor: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let userID, clinicID: String
    let createdAt, updatedAt: String?
    let clinic: ClinicClinicOfDoctor

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case userID = "user_id"
        case clinicID = "clinic_id"
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
        case clinic
    }
}


struct ClinicClinicOfDoctor: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name, status, createdAt: String
    let updatedAt: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, status
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
    }
}


struct EducationOfDoctor: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let userID, instituteName, course, year: String
    let createdAt, updatedAt: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case userID = "user_id"
        case instituteName = "institute_name"
        case course, year
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
    }
}


struct ExperienceOfDoctor: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let userID, hospitalName, position, year: String
    let createdAt, updatedAt: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case userID = "user_id"
        case hospitalName = "hospital_name"
        case position, year
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
    }
}


(Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "clinic", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"clinic\", intValue: nil) (\"clinic\").", underlyingError: nil)))))
```

Comment: where is jsonMapping code ?

Comment: @TaimoorSuleman it should be automatically synthetized  by the compiler

Comment: I don't see a problem in the mentioned code for the above response. Paste the more data of response so it can be verified.

Comment: @AnkitJayaswal i have given error message     (Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.decodingFailed(error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "clinic", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"clinic\", intValue: nil) (\"clinic\").", underlyingError: nil)))))

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with my own response of a web API and I think the problem lies with the datatype which is defined in the structs.

```
"clinic": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Al Azhar Hospital",
            "status": "1",
            "created_at": "2019-04-18 07:01:07",
            "updated_at": null
        }
```

Whichever data you are getting in the numeric form should be saved to the Int datatype as below.

```
struct ClinicClinicOfDoctor: Codable {
    let id, status : Int
    let name, createdAt: String
    let updatedAt: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, name, status
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
    }
}
```

Please verify the values in the response, datatypes and change all the models accordingly.
Hope this helps you in some way.